# Unicast image transmission using Xbee

Tags: arduino-mega, communication, xbee

I've been working on image transmission using XBee S2B Pro modules and Arduino Mega. Main task is to transmit a jpg image taken by a jpeg serial camera at the transmitter and send it to a microSD memory at the receiver, but I've been dealing with one unique trouble: I need a delay of 2 seconds to send and receive 1 byte successfully. If I set fewer seconds I lose information and the received image gets corrupted. Here you will see my codes:

Transmitter code:

```cpp
byte ZERO = 0x00;
byte incomingbyte;
long int a=0x0000,j=0,k=0,count=0,i=0;
uint8_t MH,ML;
boolean EndFlag=0;

void SendResetCmd();
void SetBaudRateCmd();
void SetImageSizeCmd();
void SendTakePhotoCmd();
void SendReadDataCmd();
void StopTakePhotoCmd();

void setup()
{   
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  } 
  Serial1.begin(38400);
}

void loop()
{
  byte a[32];
  int ii;
  SendResetCmd();
  delay(4000);                            
  SendTakePhotoCmd();
  delay(1000);     
  while(Serial1.available()>0)
  {
    incomingbyte=Serial1.read();
  }
  while(!EndFlag)
  {
    j=0;
    k=0;
    count=0;
    SendReadDataCmd();
    delay(20); 
    while(Serial1.available()>0)
    {
      incomingbyte=Serial1.read();
      k++;
      if((k>5)&&(j<32)&&(!EndFlag))
      {
        a[j]=incomingbyte;
        if((a[j-1]==0xFF)&&(a[j]==0xD9))     //tell if the picture is finished
          EndFlag=1;
        j++;
        count++;
      }
    }
    for(j=0;j<count;j++)
    {
      Serial.write(a[j]);
      delay(2000);// observe the image through serial port
    }
    i++;
  } 
  while(1);
}

void SendResetCmd()
{
  Serial1.write(0x56);
  Serial1.write(ZERO);
  Serial1.write(0x26);
  Serial1.write(ZERO);
}

void SetImageSizeCmd()
{
  Serial1.write(0x56);
  Serial1.write(ZERO);
  Serial1.write(0x31);
  Serial1.write(0x05);
  Serial1.write(0x04);
  Serial1.write(0x01);
  Serial1.write(ZERO);
  Serial1.write(0x19);
  Serial1.write(0x11);
}

void SetBaudRateCmd()
{
  Serial1.write(0x56);
  Serial1.write(ZERO);
  Serial1.write(0x24);
  Serial1.write(0x03);
  Serial1.write(0x01);
  Serial1.write(0x2A); 
  Serial1.write(0xC8);
}

void SendTakePhotoCmd()
{
  Serial1.write(0x56);
  Serial1.write(ZERO);
  Serial1.write(0x36);
  Serial1.write(0x01);
  Serial1.write(ZERO);
}

void SendReadDataCmd()
{
  MH=a/0x100;
  ML=a%0x100;
  Serial1.write(0x56);
  Serial1.write(ZERO);
  Serial1.write(0x32);
  Serial1.write(0x0c);
  Serial1.write(ZERO);
  Serial1.write(0x0a);
  Serial1.write(ZERO);
  Serial1.write(ZERO);
  Serial1.write(MH);
  Serial1.write(ML);
  Serial1.write(ZERO);
  Serial1.write(ZERO);
  Serial1.write(ZERO);
  Serial1.write(0x20);
  Serial1.write(ZERO);
  Serial1.write(0x0a);
  a+=0x20;
}

void StopTakePhotoCmd()
{
  Serial1.write(0x56);
  Serial1.write(ZERO);
  Serial1.write(0x36);
  Serial1.write(0x01);
  Serial1.write(0x03);
}
```

Receiver code:

```cpp
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>

File myFile;
int pinCS = 53; // Pin 10 on Arduino Uno

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pinCS, OUTPUT);
  if (!SD.begin()) {
    return;
  }
}

void loop() {
  byte buf[5000];
  if (Serial.available()>0)
  {
    myFile = SD.open("imgrx.jpg", FILE_WRITE);
    Serial.readBytes(buf,sizeof(buf));
    Serial.println((byte)*buf);
    myFile.write((byte)*buf);
    while(Serial.available()>0) Serial.read();
  }
  else{
    myFile.close();
  }
}
```

I've tried a MicroSD -> XBEE -> MicroSD also and that trouble continued there, maybe I've passed through something and I'd like to tell me where. Let me add these methods give me images identical to the ones I send, so even slowly, it's very effective. I changed baudrates without any success. Xbee adresses are connected as unicast. I also tried using only `Serial.readBytes` and I got Bytes faster but as decimal values and is unreadable.

I would really appreciate any information or experience approach to solve this problem. Ask me anything you don't understand about my question.

Comment: Learn how to read serial. There is **never** any cause to use `delay()`.

Comment: Problem is I need to use that delay, is practically sending 1 byte and waiting 2 secs until receiver read it and it's ready to receive a new one so I send a next byte, without it I receive anything. Could you please give me a more specific reference? Thanks

Comment: Your biggest failing is assuming that when the first byte arrives the whole thing is available. That is *never* true - you need to have some concept of how much data is being sent, and where the end of it is. Not just make incorrect assumptions.

Comment: Ok, got it. I'll improve transmission and searching for more information. Thanks